# In HP-UX, how can I log Informational Only system event messages in syslog.log?

Tags: logs, syslog, hp-ux

I was getting some Informational Only single-bit memory errors on a server for at least three weeks, but I only happened to notice them because I went looking through the SEL via the MP console for an unrelated reason. I would like to be automatically notified about things like this, maybe by having them logged to syslog.log and having a daily cron job that sends out new EMS entries from the log via email.

So my question is, given my syslog.conf file (below), why aren't all Informational Only entries already being logged in the syslog.log? My understanding is that "*.info;mail.none" means all messages Informational and above (except mail messages) should be logged to syslog.log, but none of them were in there, and I received dozens. Are they considered mail messages? Or is it just that an Informational Only message in the SEL is a separate thing from an event that would be logged by syslogd?

```
# @(#)B.11.31_LR 
#
# syslogd configuration file.
#
# See syslogd(1M) for information about the format of this file.
#
mail.debug      /var/adm/syslog/mail.log
*.info;mail.none    /var/adm/syslog/syslog.log
*.alert         /dev/console
*.alert         root
*.emerg         *
```

This is obviously for an HP-UX 11i v3 server, but I would like to set up some v2 servers the same way, so if there are any differences between configuring the two, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You are refering to SEL (System Event Log) which is outside HP-UX. When you log into MP (Managment Platform (*)) (or GSP (Global System processor (*))), you are not into HP-UX. You can power off host from MP, how can HP-UX kernel would log event while powered off ?

Critical failure (processor, memory, network card and fiber channel card) would log an event (and cause kernel panic for processor and memory), while informational event would not pe registred in HP-UX level.

Some HP-UX utilities would in 11iV1/11iV2 log event from MP, I might update when I'll get to an HP plateform.

(*) I've been using thoses acronym for far too long,I no longer know precisely what they stand for ...

Answer (score 0):

Not all applications tie into syslog.  Each application has to be programmed for that to happen.  The application that you mention might be one of these.  I seem to recall that this might be one of those applications.